# Unbuffer file write that is unicode compliant and cross-plat

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on some encryption app and need to do some unbuffered file writes.

I don't know what function I can use for this.

**To be clear, I am implementing a callback function for write, and a callback function for read, and these will handle the writing or reading when any 3rd party application in the OS wants to write to or read from the hdd.**

NEED:
-I need to work with files that have unicode names.
-I need to write in unbuffered mode.
-I need to do this for Windows, Linux, Mac.

I use C++ and Qt.  While QFile does have syntax for opening files in unbuffered mode, the docs say that it does not work with Windows (that is, QFile is always in buffered mode in Windows).

This cause my app to crash due to Windows delayed write errors. Ideally, I would not like to use a separate function(+lib) for each type of OS, but I realize that my options may not be great in my quest for cross-platform compatibility.  At any rate, I look forward to suggestions as to what functions I should use for each platform if there does not exist one that can do this for all 3.

Comment: What do you mean by unbuffered? No buffer in user space? No buffering by operating system? No buffering by HDD?

Comment: By unbuffered I mean that writes should happen as soon as possible without pooling the write requests into a buffer in the hope for minimizing i/o.  When I call write, I need it to actually really write to hdd. So in this regard, I'd like to skip all buffers that can be skipped. Prob I can not skip the hdd chache but that may be ok.  I don't want the OS to do a delayed write.

Answer (score 2):

- For Windows, you need [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) function with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag.
- On Linux you need `open()` with `O_DIRECT` option, but note that it is supported only since 2.4.10 kernel.
- On OS X, you need to call [`fsync()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/fsync.2.html) after each write.

But I must warn you that unbuffered I/O does not minimize disk I/O and is most likely to degrade performance of your application a lot. Don't do a direct I/O unless you really know what you are doing, know how OS buffering affects performance and have a clear explanation as to why unbuffered I/O will be faster. If you still want to proceed, don't forget to measure performance before and after. Your chances of doing a false optimization, and even making things a lot worse, are 9 out of 10.

As for Unicode compliance - it doesn't matter. Write takes a memory address and a number of bytes to write. You can write unicode, ASCII, any binary data etc. In case with Unicode you just have to remember not to confuse string length with string size.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Vlad.  I will try your suggestions. A few comments quickly. About the unicode, I know what I write does not matter, when I say unicode compliant I mean that the name of the file that I open so that I can write to it has a unicode name. Therefore, if the open function does not support unicode chars it will not be able to open the file (get a handle on the file) so that I can write to it.  For example fstream::open() can not open a file with a unicode file name. Is this the same "open()" that you suggested for Linux?

Comment: @user440297: No, what you are talking about are wrappers. I am not very familiar with them. `open()` is a POSIX system call. Whatever you may happen to use, it will call `open()` at the end of the day to open a file. Whether Unicode is supported or not, depends on a filesystem driver as well. For example, OS X HFS supports it, but still has its limitations. In Linux, unicode is supported through-out the system out of the box without writing any special code, so you don't have to worry about it at all. Windows, however, is an exception. There is `CreateFile` function, and it has two equivalents